# Consuming ADF BC Rest Services using the ADF Date Control causes Date field type conversion

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, data-controls

I have created some REST services using Oracle ADF 12.2 and I am trying to consume them in another ADF Fusion Application.
One of the exposed VO has a date field, I have left this field with the default UI hints and no Date formatter configured.

The Attribute in the EO with the Date field is as below.

```
<Attribute
Name="LastUpdated"
ColumnName="LAST_UPDATED"
SQLType="DATE"
Type="oracle.jbo.domain.Date"
ColumnType="DATE"
TableName="APPLICANT">
<Properties>
  <SchemaBasedProperties>
    <LABEL
      ResId="com.oracle.roshan.demo.services.eo.Applicant.LastUpdated_LABEL"/>
    <DISPLAYWIDTH
      Value="15"/>
  </SchemaBasedProperties>
</Properties>
```

The Attribute in the VO with the Date field is as below.

```
 <ViewAttribute
        Name="LastUpdated"
        PrecisionRule="true"
        EntityAttrName="LastUpdated"
        EntityUsage="Applicant"
        AliasName="LAST_UPDATED"/>
```

The ADFBC Rest generates the following when I do a get on the describe URI on the resource.

```
{
  "name": "LastUpdated",
  "type": "datetime",
  "updatable": true,
  "mandatory": false,
  "queryable": true,
  "allowChanges": "always",
  "title": "Last Updated",
  "properties": {
    "DISPLAYWIDTH": "15"
  }
},
```

In the Client ADF Application, I consumed this service and generated the DataControl. I see that the field is now typed to java.sql.Timestamp.

[The ADF model in the Client Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCuR9.png)

When I run the DataControl and edit this field in any row and submit, I got a 500 error response.

[The error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQr7R.png)

I don't see any logs as well in the WebLogic server logs.

I am new to Oracle ADF, so I might have missed out on some configuration for this to happen. Please be gentle :)

Comment: press on Show Stack Trace button on the screen, you will see the error there.

Comment: That gives me the client side error logs correct?